# how to display whole image on fixed size of canvas?

Tags: java, swing, applet

i am using Jtree for image list and displaying the selected image, but problem is that if the image size is larger than the canvas size(i.e. 300 X 300) it displays only top left of the image, how to display the whole image in fixed size canvas?

i am using following code:

```
private void displayImage(File file) {

    try 
    {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
        ta.Picture = image;
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {}

    Graphics g = ta.imageCanvas.getGraphics();
    g.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
    g.drawImage(ta.Picture, 00, 00, this);

} // displayImage

public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    FileTreeNode node = (FileTreeNode) tree.getLastSelectedPathComponent();

    if (node.isLeaf()) 
    {

        currentFile = node.file;

        File ff = new File("F:/images_blue/" + currentFile.getName());
        displayImage(ff);

    } else
        currentFile = null;

}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797933/jpanel-resize-on-repaint/12798480#12798480) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548808/scale-the-imageicon-automatically-to-label-size/14553003#14553003)

Comment: BTW - Applet + `BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);` is going to be a disaster at time of deployment.  Resources for applets would typically be accessed by URL formed relative to the code or document base of the applet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just like to point out that...

```
Graphics g = ta.imageCanvas.getGraphics();
g.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
g.drawImage(ta.Picture, 00, 00, this);
```

Is a really bad idea.

`getGraphics` may return `null` and is, at best, simply a snapshot of the last repaint cycle and could be invalidated or dereferenced on the next paint cycle.

You should be extending from something like `JPanel` and overriding the `paintComponent` method.  This would allow you to supply a getter and setter as apart of the image management and allow you to produce the scaled image in a self contained and reusable manner

You check out [Perfoming Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for me information

And, as per my comment, you might like to check out these previous questions for examples

- [Scale the ImageIcon automatically to label size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548808/scale-the-imageicon-automatically-to-label-size/14553003#14553003)
- [Jpanel resize on repaint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797933/jpanel-resize-on-repaint/12798480#12798480)
- [Quality of Image after resize very low -- Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752)
- [Java: maintaining aspect ratio of JPanel background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959758/java-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-jpanel-background-image/11959928#11959928)

Comment: +1 .. and I luurv the linked examples too :P. @mohit_pipariya See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12475560/1133011) variation and [expanded example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660122/image-resizing-and-displaying-in-a-jpanel-or-a-jlabel-without-loss-of-quality/12660146#12660146).

Answer (score 1):

you can scale BufferedImage like this..

```
BufferedImage before = getBufferedImage(encoded);
int w = before.getWidth();
int h = before.getHeight();
BufferedImage after = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
at.scale(2.0, 2.0);
AffineTransformOp scaleOp = 
   new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
after = scaleOp.filter(before, after);
```

[I found the snippet here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216123/how-to-scale-a-bufferedimage)

Comment: Isn't that going to scale the image to twice its size?

Comment: @user1983527 i want to reduce the size ,will it work if i keep the scale=0.5 ?  and what is encoded in above code?

Comment: @MadProgrammer *"Yes, if you use a fraction value below zero it will down scale the image"*  By 'value below zero' DYM 'value below one'?

Comment: @mohit_pipariya Yes, if you use a fraction value below one it will down scale the image. What do you mean by "encoded"?