# Image resizing and displaying in a JPanel or a JLabel without loss of quality

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jpeg, jlabel

I'm developing a java program to capture employee images at the time of registration using a webcam. I can obtain the picture without any problem, and save it in my C: drive but upon retrieval of the image only a part of the image is displayed on the label. Is there a way of re sizing the JPEG before saving it? or before displaying it? like shrinking it without a quality loss.

okay guys... here goes:- I have commented the code in the way I have used them.

```
//This method will capture the image from the interface and save it under the unique employee ID
public String captureImage(int picId){

    FrameGrabbingControl ControlFG = (FrameGrabbingControl)

    broadcast.getControl("javax.media.control.FrameGrabbingControl");

    Buffer buffer = ControlFG.grabFrame();

    BufferToImage image = new BufferToImage((VideoFormat)buffer.getFormat());

    img = image.createImage(buffer);

    path="c:\\employee"+picId+".jpg";

    saveJPG(img,path);//method will save the image

    return path;

}

 public void saveJPG(Image img, String s){***//method will save the image***

    System.out.println(s);

    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null),

    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();

    g2.drawImage(img,null,null);

    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try{

    out = new FileOutputStream(s);

    }
    catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException io){

    System.out.println("File Not Found");
    }

    JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(out);

    JPEGEncodeParam param = encoder.getDefaultJPEGEncodeParam(bi);

    param.setQuality(0.5f,false);

    encoder.setJPEGEncodeParam(param);

    try
    {
    encoder.encode(bi);
    out.close();
    }

    catch (java.io.IOException io)
    {
    System.out.println("IOException");
    }
    }
```

maybe I can scale the image while saving.. so that I can retrieve the scaled image..

Comment: *"shrinking it without a quality loss"*  That is not possible.  Various smoothing techniques can partly hide the artifacts of image resize, but lower the resolution in WxH and the image 'quality' must be less.

Comment: @AndrewThompson yeah thats true.... a drop in quality is alright but the entire image is not getting displayed...so far only a part of the shrunk image was all i could obtain..

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Perhaps hot-link to one of [these images](http://pscode.org/media/#image).

Comment: For better help sooner (apart from providing an SSCCE, as already mentioned by @AndrewThompson) try to make reading your question enjoyable by a) learning and sticking to java naming conventions b) completely (and consistently!) formatting the code (there's a help button which comes up with a how-to when clicked :-)

Comment: if you are really interested in quality, there isn't any way around reading up on the basics of graphics2D options, f.i. an early blog http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html or filtyRichClients

Answer (score 12):

Of course you can resize the image there are many different ways like [`Image#getScaledInstance(int width,int height,int hints)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance%28int,%20int,%20int%29), but [this has its perils](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html).

The main problem being:

> Image.getScaledInstance() does not return a finished, scaled image. It
>   leaves much of the scaling work for a later time when the image pixels
>   are used.

I would not recommend using it but [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.awt/ImagegetScaledInstanceintwidthintheightinthints.htm) is a nice example.

Alternatively you can use this method:

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

public class ImgUtils {

public BufferedImage scaleImage(int WIDTH, int HEIGHT, String filename) {
    BufferedImage bi = null;
    try {
        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(filename);//path to image
        bi = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) bi.createGraphics();
        g2d.addRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY));
        g2d.drawImage(ii.getImage(), 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return bi;
}

}
```

you'd use it like:

```
final BufferedImage img=new ImgUtils().scaleImage(200,200,"c:/test.jpg");
//create label with image as background
JLabel label=new JLabel(new ImageIcon((Image)img));
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is a small example I made:

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JavaApplication117 {

    //change this to your own
    static String filename="c:/test.jpg";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JavaApplication117().createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        initComponents(frame);

        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initComponents(JFrame frame) {
        final BufferedImage img = new ImgUtils().scaleImage(200, 200, filename);
        //create label with image as background
        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon((Image) img));

        frame.getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}

class ImgUtils {

    public BufferedImage scaleImage(int WIDTH, int HEIGHT, String filename) {
        BufferedImage bi = null;
        try {
            ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(filename);//path to image
            bi = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) bi.createGraphics();
            g2d.addRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY));
            g2d.drawImage(ii.getImage(), 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return bi;
    }
}
```

**References:**

- [resizing image java getScaledInstance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252983/resizing-image-java-getscaledinstance)

Comment: i modified the code... so that the buffered image returned is displayed on a jlabel, but still the full image is not displayed on the label, i'd try the overriding and get back ta you.. thanks again!:)!

Comment: Is there a good reason to extend `JLabel` and not simply setting the image as an icon on the `JLabel` without anything else ?

Comment: @DavidKroukamp nope still the image is not shrunk... only a part of the image is displayed...!

Comment: i think the image has to be cropped before saving it.... any ideas on that guys? thanks again! :)!

Comment: @DilshanRanaweera then something else is at fault. See my upadate. If it still does not work then i'd suggest posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @DavidKroukamp thanks a lot... i'll try and post a SSCCE if needed! cheerz! :)!

Comment: beware: quality detoriates if the downscaled with/height is less than about half the original ..