# How to set digital clock font in JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jbutton, jlabel

I am creating a digital clock using Java and I have done that.
Now I want to set the font of digital clock in the `JLabel` which is showing the time.
I am applying the font with the help of following code.

```
try {
    Font f1= new Font("Digital-7" ,Font.BOLD,28);
    jLabel1.setFont(f1);
} catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: And your problem is...?

Comment: I want to set digital font that is not being set

Comment: So you're saying that the code above doesn't work (note that we cannot assume anything about your problem and must base all on what you *specifically* tell us)? If so, are you sure that this font exists on the system? That it is spelled correctly? That it is available in bold style and at that size?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

+1 HovercrafFullOfEels comments.

I dont think I have seen *Digital-7* font pre-installed (well at least not on Windows OS) perhaps you need the [font file](http://www.dafont.com/digital-7.font), you would than load the font file and only than can it be used.

See below for loading a font file and than using it (I have omitted error handling for readability):

```
String filename="path/to/file/whatever.ttf";//this is for testing normally we would store the font file in our app (knows as an embedded resource), see this for help on that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796331/jar-embedded-resources-nullpointerexception/13797070#13797070

Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File(filename));
font = font.deriveFont(Font.BOLD,28);

GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
ge.registerFont(font);

JLabel l = new JLabel("Some Text");
l.setFont(font);
```

Comment: @nIcEcOw +1 hehe Thank you :)... and when will you be joining? Just gotta Stay up a few late nights :P

Comment: You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-). Now a days learning C and C#, LOL, finding that a bit hard to grasp :-), so seldom find time to answer Java questions :(

Comment: @nIcEcOw Lol C?!!! Ahh I want to learn that too, but yup, the syntax already confuzzles me. As for C#, when I get my skills up to standards Im sure to find you roaming the C# forum answering questions :)