# Images in jar file

Tags: java, swing, jar, embedded-resource

I made a java application and bundled all classes in jar file.When I run the project from eclipse my app is running successfully,but it is not fetching the images from the desired directory.Please let me know how can we present these image files to the end user (like we present .jar file)

Comment: How are you reading your images? Where are they placed? Do you want to include them inside jar or to place them in somewhere else?

Comment: Can you share the details about the directory. Also share your code for better help

Comment: Those resources are known as [tag:embedded-resource]s.  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796331/jar-embedded-resources-nullpointerexception/13797070#13797070) answer for help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to implement your own class loader to load embedded resources.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getResourceAsStream()` resp. `getResource()` in your code. That way you will be able to use the same code whether you decide to put your images in a jar or in a directory. A good explanation can be found [here](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/getresourceasstream.html).
Concerning the right path where to put your images during Eclipse development, follow [this recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270197/java-in-eclipse-where-do-i-put-files-on-the-filesystem-that-i-want-to-load-usin).

Answer (score 0):

It should work this way:

```
new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(imagePath))
```