# Trouble reading in image after exporting to a runnable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, javax.imageio

I have this issue where my program works fine in eclipse, correctly creating images to be made into JLabels, but when I try to export my program into a runnable jar, it no longer works. I've done some debugging and managed to figure out that the method I have for creating the images returns does not work after exporting. I assume this is because making the program a runnable jar file changes the paths of the files, but I'm left clueless as to how to fix it. Relevant details below, any help is appreciated!

```
// This is the method that calls the method to create the pictures
public static void buildMapper() {
        readPics();
    ...

    // Create JLabel pictures
        JLabel f1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(floor1.getScaledInstance(1275, 825, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
    ..
}

private static void readPics() {
        try {
            // Load floors
            floor1 = ImageIO.read(new File("src\\resources\\floor1.png"));
      ...
    }catch(IOException ex){ System.out.println("IO Exception"); }
}
// floor1 is a private static BufferedImage
```

Here is how I've set up my project tree. The resources folder just contains all the images I've used, like `floor1.png`
[Project Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYnib.png)

Again, any help would be greatly appreciated! This is the first time I've done a programming project to this big of a scope, involving a lot of things I had to learn myself, so there's bound to be plenty of errors to learn from!

edit: I managed to fix it. If anyone else is struggling, my solution was to change the line `floor1 = ImageIO.read(new File("src\\resources\\floor1.png"));` to `floor1 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/resources/floor1.png"));`. I also had to make the method not static, since this.getClass() cannot be called in a static method.

Comment: This is well known problem, example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17611546/13510609

Comment: What you sent helped a lot, I got to work! Thank you!