# GUI with Java GUI Builder for uploading an image and displaying to a panel(inside the GUI) dynamically

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jbutton

I'm relatively new to GUI building.

I want to make a GUI with a button(that I already have) that a user can press and select an image and then dynamically, this image to be loaded in the GUI in a panel.
I want the image to change dynamically every time the user browses an image.

So far my code is that .... But I cant connect the button to a JPanel or something.

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.*;

public class WebAppImg extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private int image_height;
    private int image_aspect_ratio;
    private Graphics2D engine;
    private JLabel photoComponent;    

    /**
     * Creates new form WebAppImg
     */
    public WebAppImg() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(600, 480));

        jButton1.setText("Attach");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("label2");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(154, 154, 154)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 239, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(133, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 199, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(120, 120, 120))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(57, 57, 57)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 163, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 141, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(35, 35, 35))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
        JInternalFrame jInternalFrame1 = new JInternalFrame();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        String filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
        jTextField1.setText(filename);
        jInternalFrame1.getDesktopIcon();
    }

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(WebAppImg.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(WebAppImg.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(WebAppImg.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(WebAppImg.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new WebAppImg().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        //Create a file chooser

    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Comment: *But I cant connect the button to a JPanel or something* The code does as is expected of it... could you please eloborate. And what is the JInternalFrame for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is the chosen image to be shown, if so change you `jButton1ActionPerformed` method to this:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    String filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
    jTextField1.setText(filename);
    try {
        ImageIcon ii=new ImageIcon(scaleImage(120, 120, ImageIO.read(new File(f.getAbsolutePath()))));//get the image from file chooser and scale it to match JLabel size
        jLabel1.setIcon(ii);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static BufferedImage scaleImage(int w, int h, BufferedImage img) throws Exception {
    BufferedImage bi;
    bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) bi.createGraphics();
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.addRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY));
    g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h, null);
    g2d.dispose();
    return bi;
}
```

an even better solution would see you using a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) to load the image so UI doesnt become unresponsive (if the image is large):

```
private ImageIcon ii;

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    final File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
    String filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
    if (f == null) {
        return;
    }
    jTextField1.setText(filename);

    SwingWorker sw = new SwingWorker() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(5000);//simulate large image takes long to load
            ii = new ImageIcon(scaleImage(120, 120, ImageIO.read(new File(f.getAbsolutePath()))));
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() { 
            super.done();
            jLabel1.setIcon(ii);
        }
    };
    sw.execute();

}
```

Comment: Thanks David. So simple. ;) Happy new year to all of you!

Comment: And David. What is the purpose of this class that you added named 'scaleImage' ? Thanks.

Comment: @GeorgeKourou see  my update. And also that method is just used to scale the image to fit the JLabel instead of using `getScaledInstance` which has known issues. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660122/image-resizing-and-displaying-in-a-jpanel-or-a-jlabel-without-loss-of-quality/12660146#12660146) for more

Comment: your latest update doesn't work for me. The image doesnt seem to appear on the panel..(The first solution cuts the images in half,so maybe I'll need the second solution). Thanks in advance.

Comment: The difference between the 2 solutions is the SwingWorker, the reason the image is getting cut in half is because the JLabel has a set width and height, if you dont scale the image to fit than ofcourse that will happen

Comment: Thanks David I saw that just after posting the comment. Thanks for your help.